# Не идет запись в дб с формы

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Здравствуйте.

Проблема ввела в ступор.

Сделал простенькую регистрацию для проекта.

Но не идет запись имени пользователя и его пароль не запоминается, но id в БД создается новый.

Код контроллера:

```
 public function actionSignup(){
    if (!Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
        return $this->goHome();
    }
    $model = new SignupForm();
    if($model->load(\Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()){
        $user = new User();
        $user->username = $model->username;
        $user->password = \Yii::$app->security->generatePasswordHash($model->password);
        if($user->save()){
            return $this->goHome();
        }
    }

    return $this->render('signup',compact('model'));
}
```

Код модели:

```
class SignupForm extends Model{
public $username;
public $password;

public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['username','password'],'required', 'message'=>'Заполните поле'],
    ];
}

public function attributes()
{
    return [
        'username' => 'Логин',
        'password' => 'Пароль',
    ];
}
```

}

Код вьюшки:

```html
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: sharavin
 * Date: 28.07.2017
 * Time: 16:33
 */
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
?>
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin() ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'username') ?>
<?= $form->field($model, 'password')->passwordInput() ?>
<div class="form-group">
    <div>
        <?= Html::submitButton('Регистрация', ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php ActiveForm::end() ?>
```

Вот почему такое может быть?

Бд работает, подключена.

Код модели User:

```html
<?php

namespace app\models;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;
use yii\web\IdentityInterface;


class User extends ActiveRecord implements IdentityInterface
{
    public $id;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $authKey;
    public $accessToken;

    private static $users = [
        '100' => [
            'id' => '100',
            'username' => 'admin',
            'password' => 'admin',
            'authKey' => 'test100key',
            'accessToken' => '100-token',
        ],
        '101' => [
            'id' => '101',
            'username' => 'demo',
            'password' => 'demo',
            'authKey' => 'test101key',
            'accessToken' => '101-token',
        ],
    ];


    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentity($id)
    {
        return isset(self::$users[$id]) ? new static(self::$users[$id]) : null;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public static function findIdentityByAccessToken($token, $type = null)
    {
        foreach (self::$users as $user) {
            if ($user['accessToken'] === $token) {
                return new static($user);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Finds user by username
     *
     * @param string $username
     * @return static|null
     */
    public static function findByUsername($username)
    {
        foreach (self::$users as $user) {
            if (strcasecmp($user['username'], $username) === 0) {
                return new static($user);
            }
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getAuthKey()
    {
        return $this->authKey;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function validateAuthKey($authKey)
    {
        return $this->authKey === $authKey;
    }

    /**
     * Validates password
     *
     * @param string $password password to validate
     * @return bool if password provided is valid for current user
     */
    public function validatePassword($password)
    {
        return $this->password === $password;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проблема в том, что Yii не знает, что нужно делать с полями $username и $password. Для того чтобы поля обрабатывались нужно определить метод rules()

```
/**
 * @inheritdoc
 */
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['id', 'username'], 'string', 'max' => 255],
    ];
}
```

Также приведённая вами модель User, предназначена для работы с вашим массивом $users. Для того, чтобы полностью воспользоваться базой данных, нужно: убрать массив $users и изменить методы findIdentity, findIdentityByAccessToken, findByUsername. [Пример здесь](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/common/models/User.php)

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте код модели `User`
P.S. У расширенной версии форма регистрации идет по умолчанию, возьмите [ёё](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/frontend/models/SignupForm.php)
код для примера

Comment: @vityaprp Добавил.

Comment: не вижу функции на валидалию входящих параметров, возможно проблема в этом

Comment: попробуйте воспользоваться [примером](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced/blob/master/common/models/User.php)

Comment: Сейчас попробую. Хм. Но валидацию сделал ведь в модели регистрации... 
Хм. Или там нужно. 
Так. Сейчас попробую.

Comment: Валидация нужна для каждой формы которая `extends ActiveRecord` (работает с базой данных)

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего из-за того, что rules() в модели user не прописана